# How to turn note into checklist

Tags: google-keep

In Google Keep, is it possible to convert a normal list into a checkbox list? Equivalently, is it possible to unhide check boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add checkboxes: open the note, click on the + symbol at the bottom left corner and click "Checkboxes""

To remove checkboxes: open the note, click on the 3 vertical dots on the top right corner and click "Hide Checkboxes"

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do this on the Android app, but you can go to https://keep.google.com/ for the web version, click on the note, click on the 3 dots and click "show checkboxes". When the Android app syncs, it will also have the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the note and click on little + under the list on the left side and then select *Checkboxes*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in android phone...!

1. Select the desire text
2. Cut it
3. Activate the checkbox back again
4. Paste the text

The easy way...!